# Websocket Proxy using Play 2.6 and akka streams

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-http, akka-stream

I'm trying to create a simple Proxy for Websocket connections using Play and akka streams. 
The traffic flow is like this:

```
(Client) request  ->         -> request (Server)
                      Proxy 
(Client) response <-         <- response (Server)
```

I came up with the following code after following some examples:

```
def socket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { request =>

val uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString

// wsOut - actor that deals with incoming websocket frame from the Client
// wsIn - publisher of the frame for the Server
val (wsOut: ActorRef, wsIn: Publisher[String]) = {
  val source: Source[String, ActorRef] = Source.actorRef[String](10, OverflowStrategy.dropTail)
  val sink: Sink[String, Publisher[String]] = Sink.asPublisher(fanout = false)
  source.toMat(sink)(Keep.both).run()
}

// sink that deals with the incoming messages from the Server
val serverIncoming: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
  Sink.foreach[Message] {
    case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
      println("The server has sent: " + message.text)
  }

// source for sending a message over the WebSocket
val serverOutgoing = Source.fromPublisher(wsIn).map(TextMessage(_))

// flow to use (note: not re-usable!)
val webSocketFlow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("ws://0.0.0.0:6000"))

// the materialized value is a tuple with
// upgradeResponse is a Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse] that
// completes or fails when the connection succeeds or fails
// and closed is a Future[Done] with the stream completion from the incoming sink
val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
serverOutgoing
  .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.right) // keep the materialized Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]
  .toMat(serverIncoming)(Keep.both) // also keep the Future[Done]
  .run()

// just like a regular http request we can access response status which is available via upgrade.response.status
// status code 101 (Switching Protocols) indicates that server support WebSockets
val connected = upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
  if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
    Future.successful(Done)
  } else {
    throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
  }
}

// in a real application you would not side effect here
connected.onComplete(println)
closed.foreach(_ => println("closed"))

val actor = system.actorOf(WebSocketProxyActor.props(wsOut, uuid))
val finalFlow = {
  val sink = Sink.actorRef(actor, akka.actor.Status.Success(()))
  val source = Source.maybe[String] // what the client receives. How to connect with the serverIncoming sink ???
  Flow.fromSinkAndSource(sink, source)
}

finalFlow
```

With this code, the traffic goes from the Client to the Proxy to the Server, back to the Proxy and that's it. It doesn't reach further to the Client. How can I fix this ?
I think I need to somehow connect the `serverIncoming` sink to the `source` in the `finalFlow`, but I can't figure out how to do it...

Or am I totally wrong with this approach ? Is it better to use a `Bidiflow` or a `Graph` ? I'm new to akka streams and still trying to figure things out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work. Note: I've implemented both the server socket and the proxy socket in the same controller, but you can split them or deploy the same controller on separate instances. The ws url to the 'upper' service will need to be updated in both cases.

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.{Message, TextMessage, WebSocketRequest, WebSocketUpgradeResponse}
import akka.stream.Materializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow
import play.api.libs.streams.ActorFlow
import play.api.mvc._

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import scala.language.postfixOps

@Singleton
class SomeController @Inject()(implicit exec: ExecutionContext,
                                actorSystem: ActorSystem,
                                materializer: Materializer) extends Controller {

  /*--- proxy ---*/
  def websocketFlow: Flow[Message, Message, Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]] =
    Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("ws://localhost:9000/upper-socket"))

  def proxySocket: WebSocket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { _ =>
    Flow[String].map(s => TextMessage(s))
      .via(websocketFlow)
      .map(_.asTextMessage.getStrictText)
  }

  /*--- server ---*/
  class UpperService(socket: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case s: String => socket ! s.toUpperCase()
      case _ =>
    }
  }

  object UpperService {
    def props(socket: ActorRef): Props = Props(new UpperService(socket))
  }

  def upperSocket: WebSocket = WebSocket.accept[String, String] { _ =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef(out => UpperService.props(out))
  }   
}
```

You will need the routes to be set up like this:

```
GET /upper-socket controllers.SomeController.upperSocket
GET /proxy-socket controllers.SomeController.proxySocket
```

You can test by sending a string to ws://localhost:9000/proxy-socket. The answer will be the uppercased string.

There will be a timeout after 1 minute of inactivity though:

```
akka.stream.scaladsl.TcpIdleTimeoutException: TCP idle-timeout encountered on connection to [localhost:9000], no bytes passed in the last 1 minute
```

But see: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/timeouts.html on how to configure this.

Comment: This is not a Proxy. This is a very simple Server that uppercases strings and sends them back to the Client using web sockets.

Comment: @morganfreeman I meant the controller itself to be the proxy. The UpperService can be replaced by an actor that calls an external service to do real processing, something along these lines: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stream-integrations.html#Integrating_with_External_Services. But I probably do not correctly understand your problem.

Comment: True, the UpperService could in theory send the frames via a Web Socket to the Server. Tried it initially. That Web Socket to the Server is a Flow. I couldn't "connect" the receive method of the actor to the Source of the Flow and the Sink of the flow back to the `socket` (so data gets back to the client). I could initialise the Web Socket flow in the receive method, but that would open a connection to the Server each time.

Comment: I've rewritten the logic now that I think I understand your problem better.

Comment: This is insane!

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need some `akka` imports:

```scala
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.WebSocketRequest
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws.Message
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpRequest
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives.{ extractUpgradeToWebSocket, complete }
```

This is an example `App` that creates a `WebSocket` proxy, binding on `0.0.0.0` on port `80`, proxing to `ws://echo.websocket.org`:

```scala
object WebSocketProxy extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  private[this] def manipulateFlow: Flow[Message, Message, akka.NotUsed] = ???

  private[this] def webSocketFlow =
    Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("ws://echo.websocket.org"))

  private[this] val route: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any] = 
    extractUpgradeToWebSocket { upgrade =>
      val webSocketFlowProxy = manipulateFlow via webSocketFlow
      val handleWebSocketProxy = upgrade.handleMessages(webSocketFlowProxy)
      complete(handleWebSocketProxy)
    }

  private[this] val proxyBindingFuture =
    Http().bindAndHandle(route, "0.0.0.0", 80)

  println(s"Server online\nPress RETURN to stop...")
  Console.readLine()
}
```

You have to adapt it for `play` and for your application structure.

Notes:

- remember to unbind `proxyBindingFuture` and terminate the `system` in production;
- you need `manipulateFlow` only if you want to manipulate messages.

Answer (score 2):

A proxy need to provide two flows (Proxy Flow A / B):

```
(Client) request  ->  Proxy Flow A -> request (Server)

(Client) response <-  Proxy Flow B <- response (Server)
```

One option to implement such proxy flow is using ActorSubscriber and SourceQueue:

```
class Subscriber[T](proxy: ActorRef) extends ActorSubscriber {
  private var queue = Option.empty[SourceQueueWithComplete[T]] 
  def receive = {
    case Attach(sourceQueue) => queue = Some(sourceQueue)
    case msg: T => // wait until queue attached and pass forward all msgs to queue and the proxy actor
  }
}

def proxyFlow[T](proxy: ActorRef): Flow[T, ActorRef] = {
  val sink = Sink.actorSubscriber(Props(new Subscriber[T](proxy)))
  val source = Source.queue[T](...)
  Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(sink, source){ (ref, queue) =>
    ref ! Attach(queue)
    ref
  }
}
```

You can then assemble the client flow like:

```
val proxy = actorOf(...)
val requestFlow = proxyFlow[Request](proxy)
val responseFlow = proxyFlow[Response](proxy)
val finalFlow: Flow[Request, Response] = 
    requestFlow.via(webSocketFlow).via(responseFlow)
```

Answer (score 1):

As an extension of Federico's very nice solution - this code can be used in a proxy forwarding gateway service where you connect to a proxy which "pipes" the Websockets to a microservice. The code below uses Akka Http 10.2.0 and there are provisions in the code to handle upstream flow failure when the originator Websocket client disconnects - i.e., recover with case throwable added to Websocket Client Flow.

```
import akka.actor.typed.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.ws._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{HttpRequest, HttpResponse}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives.{complete, extractWebSocketUpgrade}
import akka.stream.scaladsl._

import scala.io.StdIn
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    implicit val system = ActorSystem(Behaviors.empty, "webtest")
    implicit val executionContext = system.executionContext

    def webSocketFlow =
      Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("ws://localhost:8000/ws"))
        .recover {
          case throwable: Throwable =>
            try {
              throw new RuntimeException(s"Websocket Upstream Flow failed... Message: ${throwable.getMessage}")
            } catch {
              case t: Throwable => system.log.info(t.getMessage)           //catching all Throwable exceptions
            }
            TextMessage("Websocket Upstream Flow failed...")
        }

    def routeFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Any] = extractWebSocketUpgrade { upgrade =>
      val handleWebSocketProxy = upgrade.handleMessages(webSocketFlow)
      complete(handleWebSocketProxy)
    }

    Http().newServerAt("0.0.0.0", 8080).bindFlow(routeFlow)
      .onComplete {
        case Success(_) =>
          system.log.info("Server online at http://0.0.0.0:8080")
        case Failure(ex) =>
          system.log.error("Failed to bind HTTP endpoint, terminating system", ex)
          system.terminate()
      }

    system.log.info("Press RETURN to stop...")
    StdIn.readLine()
    system.terminate()
  }

}
```

Here user/originator connects to 0.0.0.0:8080 as a proxy and is "piped" (forwarded) to localhost:8000.